# How to install Dapr on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: dapr

[Dapr](https://github.com/dapr/dapr) is new event-driven technology based on distributed building blocks and components.

How can one install the technology stack and get started with Dapr.

Comment: https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/install-dapr-selfhost/

Answer (score 1):

These are the instructions to install Dapr: https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/install-dapr/

Then, try the `Hello World` quickstart: https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/hello-world

I'd recommend the `Hello Kubernetes` quickstart next:
https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/hello-kubernetes

Once you understand those, try the other quickstarts too:
https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts

For more complex use cases, check the samples repository:
https://github.com/dapr/samples

Answer (score 0):

To get started you find basic information here https://dapr.io/ and particularly here to get in touch with the community https://github.com/dapr/dapr#community.

To catch up I suggest to look into the Build 2020 and community calls videos http://aka.ms/dapr-recordings.